# shifting bars and creating polygons inside another shape

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, flow-charts

i m trying to make this diagram and i have made this so far
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{150,150,150}

\tikzset{
    myshape/.style={
        shape=signal,
        fill=myblue,
        minimum height=1.4cm,
        minimum width=1.15cm,
        text=white,
        signal pointer angle=128,
        signal to=south,
        signal from=north,
        rotate=-90,
        transform shape
    },
    mytext/.style={
        draw=myblue,
        text width=7cm,
        minimum height=1.15cm,
        thick,
        outer sep=-0
    }  
}
\newcounter{lp}
\newcommand\MyDesc[3][]{
    \stepcounter{lp}%
    \node[myshape,#1] (desc\thelp) {};
    \node[font=\color{white}] at (desc\thelp) {#2};
    \node[mytext,anchor=north west] at (desc\thelp.north west) 
    {%

        \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-0em\relax}{#3}%
    };
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \MyDesc{\textbf{\Large 1}}{\centering \textbf{Region-based convultional neural network (R-CNN)}}
        \MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc1.north]{\textbf{\Large2}}{\centering \textbf{Single Short Multi Box Detection (SSD)}}
        \MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc2.north]{\textbf{\Large 3}}{\centering \textbf{You Only Look Once (YOLO)}}
        \MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc3.north]{\textbf{\Large 4}}{\centering \textbf{Efficient Det}}
        \MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc4.north]{\textbf{\Large 5}}{\centering \textbf{Retina Net}}
        \MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc5.north]{\textbf{\Large 6}}{\centering \textbf{Corner Net}}
        \MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc6.north]{\textbf{\Large 7}}{\centering \textbf{Cascade R-CNN}}
        \MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc7.north]{\textbf{\Large 8}}{\centering \textbf{Feature Pyramid Network (FPN)}}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks before you ask your next question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw these with a `path picture` inside a node. Note that these nodes are fixed-size. The will not adjust to the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, positioning}

\tikzset{myshape/.style={
    minimum height=1.5cm,
    minimum width=8cm,
    align=center,
    path picture={
        \node[anchor=west, draw, thick, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1.6cm, inner sep=0pt](ZZ) at (path picture bounding box.west){};
        \node[anchor=center, fill=purple, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1.3cm, inner sep=0pt] at (ZZ){#1};
        \draw[thick]([yshift=-.5*\pgflinewidth]ZZ.corner 1)--++(5,0)--([xshift=5.5cm]ZZ.corner 6)--([shift={(5,.5*\pgflinewidth)}]ZZ.corner 5)--([yshift=.5*\pgflinewidth]ZZ.corner 5);
    }
}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
\node[myshape=01] (A){Region-based convultional\\neural network (R-CNN)};
\node[myshape=02, below=of A, xshift=1cm] (B){Single Short Multi Box\\Detection (SSD)};
\node[myshape=03, below=of B, xshift=-1cm] (C){You Only Look Once (YOLO)};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```