# over laying pictures and positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, flow-charts, tikzset

using this [Link i modified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712218/316166) i could have made this
[the output i had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irjRs.png)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows.meta,
    backgrounds,
    fit,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    quotes}

\tikzset{myshape/.style={
    minimum height=3.2cm,
    minimum width=3.1cm,
    align=center,
    path picture={
        \node[anchor=center,fill=Green ,draw=Green, ultra thick,circle, minimum size=3cm, inner sep=0pt](ZZ) at (path picture bounding box.center){};
        \node[anchor=center, fill=Turquoise, circle, , minimum size=2.9cm, inner sep=0pt] at (ZZ){#1};}},
myshape2/.style={circle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    minimum width=3.1cm,
    align=center,
    path picture={
        \node[anchor=center,fill=Green ,draw=Green, ultra thick,circle, minimum size=4cm, inner sep=0pt](ZZ) at (path picture bounding box.center){};
        \node[anchor=center, fill=Turquoise, circle, , minimum size=3.8cm, inner sep=0pt] at (ZZ){#1};}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [myshape](a){Molecular \\property\\ prediction};
\node [myshape2,above right=2cm of a](b){ Material property\\ Analysis};
\node [myshape,below right=2cm of b](c){ Nano \\Materials\\ Analysis};
\node [myshape,above=2cm of b]{ Degradation \\Detection};
\node [circle,minimum width=6cm] at (b){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
**but i m trying to achive this**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution

```
\documentclass[tikz,  border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    myshape/.style={circle, minimum width=3cm, align=center,
        text width=2cm, draw=blue!60!green, thick, font=\sffamily\small, fill=white},
    ]
\draw[line width=5mm, blue!70!green!30] circle (4cm);
\node[myshape, text width=3.5cm] (MAP) {Material Property\\ Analysis};
\node[myshape] (DD) at (90:4cm) {Degradation detection};
\node[myshape] (MPP) at (210:4cm) {Molecular Property Prediction};
\node[myshape] (NMA) at (-30:4cm) {Nano Material Analysis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to be that complex. See this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{1,139,173}
\definecolor{mylightblue}{RGB}{170,204,218}
\tikzset{
myshape/.style={
circle,draw=
mydarkblue,fill=white,align=center,line width=3pt,minimum size=3.5cm
},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [mylightblue,line width=0.5cm] circle [radius=5cm];
\node [myshape,minimum size=4.5cm] at (0,0) {Molecular\\property\\prediction};
\node [myshape] at (-30:5cm) {Nano\\Materials\\Analysis};
\node [myshape] at (90:5cm) {Degradation\\Detection};
\node [myshape] at (-150:5cm) {Molecular\\property\\prediction};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]